# SQL Server 2012 setup fails immediately (Error result: -2067529723)

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server Enterprise Core 2012 w SP1 64bit (as downloaded from the Microsoft Partner Program site) on a 64-bit Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server. When simply right-clicking on SETUP.EXE in the root and selecting Run as Administrator, seemingly nothing happens. When I run it from a Command Prompt (Run as Administrator), I get this:

> An error occurred during the SQL Server 2012 Setup operation.
>
> Error result: -2067529723
>   Result facility code: 1220
>   Result error code: 5
>
> For more information, review SQL Server 2012 Setup logs in your temp
>   folder.

No log files were written anywhere. How can I find out what this error is trying to tell me and what I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted the VM, and I was then able to get the Setup to work as expected. I am disappointed that the error message did not provide any indication of what was wrong or what needed to be done to correct the situation, but rebooting seems to have resolved whatever the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message as yours.
I found out that my environment variable `temp` was pointing to an existing file, when it should be a directory.

After renaming the original file and creating a directory instead, the installation proceeded.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received this error while using a configuration file that was totally unusable.

I inherited it and (wrongly) assumed it was in working order. Instead, it had a bunch of non-valid parameters and instead of using `;` for comments, it used `#`. The logs gave this error without any useful information.

So checking your configuration file's validity with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017) might be a step worth looking at when seeing this error.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing exactly same error with error code *Error result: -2068643839*.
It was occurring when I was trying to install SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition with mounting ISO file on my Windows 10 machine. 
I googled and found some other issues getting resolved when installing by extracting ISO file instead of installing it by mounting the ISO. The error went away.